# Transform svg inside svg

Tags: svg, transform

Ok so I got two examples. First is a single svg to which I apply a transform to flip the svg horizontally:

http://jsfiddle.net/p3L95rcb/

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
viewBox="0 0 109.55 40.51" transform="scale(-1,1)">
```

Second is the same svg, only now it's wrapped inside another svg (created with snap svg):

http://jsfiddle.net/dFTtd/650/

```
<svg id="combinationDrawSvg" width="100%" height="254" class="overlap-annotations"><g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"><svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 109.55 40.51" transform="scale(-1,1)">
```

Now if I apply the same transform to the inner svg, the transform is not applied. Any thought on why the transform works in example 1 and it does not in example 2? I'm kinda stuck on this one, so some help maybe useful.

Comment: Did you try it in Firefox? Not all browsers support transform on an <svg> element but Firefox does. For cross-browser support use a <g> element instead of an <svg> element.

Comment: To expand on what Robert said, if you wrap the drawing in your inner svg with a `<g/>`, and put the transform on that, it works. Transforms on nested `<svg/>` tags make browsers grumpy

Comment: I'd `use` the first svg in the second via `<use xlink:href="#Layer_1"/>` and apply the transform to the original. Generally not good practice (as far as I know) to embed svg's directly in svg's though I'd refer more insight on that from Robert.

Comment: @RobertLongson: if I try that in the 2nd example then the image is gone. Or is that because the svg is outside of the screen?

Comment: @ChrisW. we're combining multiple svg's into one so we need embed svg's into each other...

Comment: @WillemvanBeem Sure, but a better practice for accomplishing that would be to create a base svg with a defs library and implement them with `use` [like this](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/dpamPj).

Comment: @WillemvanBeem that's correct it's outside the viewport.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm still puzzled on how to fix this. Can you show me how to fix this in the 2nd fiddle?

Comment: Ted provided more details in the comment after mine, what problem are you facing following them?

Comment: I got the following to work now in firefox:

<g><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 406.93 140.65" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="341.38235294117646" height="129.6115" x="184.8416176470588" y="76.507903" style="transform-origin: 275.576904296875px; transform: scale(-1, 1);">

But in Chrome it only works if I put the styling on the <g>, but that is no option since there are more elements inside the group and I only want to mirror one of them. Any thoughts on how to get this solution to work in both Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

use <**symbol**> element

```
<!-- id with lowercase -->
<symbol id="layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 109.55 40.51">
    <!-- your paths -->
</symbol>

<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
    <use xlink:href="#layer_1" x="0" y="0" transform-origin="50% 50%" transform="scale(-1, 1)" />
</g>
```